# How to show a derivative is a maximum, not a minimum

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am working through a maths text book. I study as a hobby. I have solved most of this problem except for the very last part.

The points A and B are on the same horizontal level and at a distance of $b$ apart. A particle P falls vertically at rest from B, so that at time $t$ its depth below B is $kt^2$, where $k$ is constant. At this time, the angle of depression of P from A is $\theta$.

Prove that $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{2bkt}{b^2 + k^2t^4}$. Show that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is greatest (and not least) when $\theta = \frac{1}{6}\pi$.

I proved the first part and to then I differentiated $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{2bkt}{b^2 + k^2t^4}$ to get the second derivative:

$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \{(b^2 + k^2t^4)(2bk) - (2bkt)(4k^3t^4)\}/(b^2 + k^2t^4)^2$

$= 0$ when $2b^3k +2bk^3t^4 - 8bk^3t^4 = 0$

$\implies b^2k = 3k^2t^4$

Now when $\theta = \frac{1}{6}\pi$, $\tan \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and

$\frac {kt^2}{b} = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, meaning $b^2 = 3k^2t^4$

So $\theta = \frac{1}{6}\pi$ is a maximum or a minimum.

But how do I show which? Taking a third derivative seems very complicated.

Comment: doing a slope test would be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that second derivative is zero when
$$b^2-3 k^2 t^4=0;\;t=\pm\sqrt[4]{\frac{b^2}{3 k^2}}$$
Compute the third derivative$^*$
$$\frac{d^3\theta}{dt^3}=-\frac{8 b k^3 t^3 \left(5 b^2-3 k^2 t^4\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^3}$$
which is negative for $t_0=\sqrt[4]{\frac{b^2}{3 k^2}}$ so that $t_0$ is a maximum.

This is called  [second derivative test][1].

---

**Alternative method**

Set second derivative positive
$$b^2-3 k^2 t^4>0\to -\sqrt[4]{\frac{b^2}{3 k^2}}<t<\sqrt[4]{\frac{b^2}{3 k^2}}$$
means that at $t_0$ the derivative goes from positive to negative therefore $t_0$ is a maximum

---

$(*)$

First derivative is
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=2 b k\left[ \frac{ t}{b^2+k^2 t^4}\right]$$
Second derivative is
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=2bk\left[\frac{1 \left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)-t \left(4 k^2 t^3\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^2}\right]=\frac{2 b k \left(b^2-3 k^2 t^4\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^2}$$

Third derivative is
$$\frac{d^3\theta}{dt^3}=2bk\left[\frac{\left(-12 k^2 t^3\right) \left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^2-2 \left(4 k^2 t^3\right) \left(b^2-3 k^2 t^4\right) \left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^4}\right]=$$
$$=-\frac{8 b k^3 t^3 \left(5 b^2-3 k^2 t^4\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^3}$$
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second-derivative_test_(single_variable)

Comment: I’m not sure what the asterisk signifies in t*

Comment: @Steblo just a tag. edited, now it is  $t_0$

Comment: I get it except for one thing: Could you tell me how you got the third derivative?:$$\frac{d^3\theta}{dt^3}=-\frac{8 b k^3 t^3 \left(5 b^2-3 k^2 t^4\right)}{\left(b^2+k^2 t^4\right)^3}$$ This is what I could not do.

Comment: @Steblo I added the calculation of the third derivative, but it is not necessary

Comment: Thanks for such a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that complicated.

$$\tan\theta\; = \; \frac{kt^2}{b}$$
$$\sec^2{\theta}\ d\theta\; = \; \frac{2ktdt}{b}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}\;= \frac{2kt \cos^2\theta}{b}$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\;= \frac{2k \cos^2\theta}{b}\; -\; \frac{4kt \cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{b}.\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

While taking 3rd derivative put $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\: = \: 0$.

Note: Use $\sin2\theta$

Comment: I don’t see where the $\cos^2 \theta$ comes from in the first line.

Comment: @Steblo Check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

To find a stationary point in general, we let the first derivative be equal to $0$. As you've said, this by itself gives us no information about whether the stationary point is a minimum or maximum. To determine which type it is, we use the second derivative of the function.

For a given curve, $y=f(x)$ which has a stationary point at $(a, f(a))$:

- If $$f''(a)<0$$
  then the stationary pint is a (local) maximum. This is because the second derivative is the rate of change of the gradient (the first derivative). If the gradient is **decreasing** at the stationary point then this means that the curve is about to slope **downwards** ; ie the stationary point is a **maximum**.
- If $$f''(a)>0$$
  then the stationary pint is a (local) minimum. This is because the second derivative is the rate of change of the gradient (the first derivative). If the gradient is **increasing** at the stationary point then this means that the curve is about to slope **upwards** ; ie the stationary point is a **minimum**.
- However, if $f''(a)=0$ then we either have a point of inflection, or a point which isn't a point of inflection (No...really? ;) ). If it isn't a point of inflection then it is more tedious to determine which type of stationary point we have. I can elaborate about this if you like.

Comment: I knew that but I was finding it hard to find and apply the second derivative.

Comment: @Steblo sorry, I misunderstood what was troubling you, my bad.